# How can I add one point to a score when the scoring system is in a loop?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1050')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random

class MainWidget(Widget):
    from controls import _keyboard_closed, _on_keyboard_down, _on_keyboard_up

    drone = None
    SCORE = 0

    clouds = []
    balloons = []

    current_speed_y = 0
    current_speed_x = 0

    drone_coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]
    balloon_coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.init_drone()

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.init_clouds, 1 / 8)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 600)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.init_balloons, 7)

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)

    def init_clouds(self, dt):
        cloud_types = ["images/cloudbig.png", "images/cloudbig1.png", "images/cloudbig2.png"]
        cloud_type = random.choice(cloud_types)

        a = self.width
        b = self.width - 100

        x = random.randint(b, a)
        y = random.randint(-100, self.height)

        cloud = Image(source=cloud_type,
                      pos=(x, y))
        self.add_widget(cloud)
        self.clouds.append(cloud)

    def move_clouds(self, *args):
        out_cloud_list = []  # If cloud not in screen remove:
        for child in self.children and self.clouds:
            if child.pos[0] < -50:
                out_cloud_list.append(child)

            else:
                child.pos[0] -= 3

        for self.cloud in out_cloud_list:
            self.remove_widget(self.cloud)

    def init_drone(self):
        self.drone = Image(source="images/drone.png",
                           pos=(100, 300))

        self.add_widget(self.drone)
        self.drone_coordinates[0] = self.drone.pos

    def init_balloons(self, dt):
        balloon_types = ["images/yellow_balloon.png", "images/green_balloon.png", "images/purple_balloon.png",
                         "images/red_balloon.png"]
        balloon_type = random.choice(balloon_types)

        x = random.randint(100, self.width)
        y = random.randint(50, 150)

        balloon = Image(source=balloon_type,
                        pos=(x, y))
        self.add_widget(balloon)
        self.balloons.append(balloon)

    def move_balloons(self):
        out_balloon_list = []  # If cloud not in screen remove:
        for child in self.children and self.balloons:
            if child.pos[0] < -50 or child.pos[1] > self.height-50:
                out_balloon_list.append(child)

            else:
                child.pos[0] -= 2
                child.pos[1] += 3

        for self.balloon in out_balloon_list:
            self.remove_widget(self.balloon)

    def get_drone_coordinates(self):
        x1, y1 = self.drone.pos
        self.drone_coordinates[0] = (x1, y1)

        x2, y2 = self.drone.pos[0] + self.drone.width, self.drone.pos[1] + self.drone.height
        self.drone_coordinates[1] = (x2, y2)

    def get_balloon_coordinates(self):
        for balloon in self.balloons:
            x1, y1 = balloon.pos[0], balloon.pos[1]
            self.balloon_coordinates[0] = (x1, y1)

            x2, y2 = balloon.pos[0] + balloon.width, balloon.pos[1] + balloon.height
            self.balloon_coordinates[1] = (x2, y2)

    def check_drone_collect_balloon(self):
        self.get_drone_coordinates()
        self.get_balloon_coordinates()

        drone_xmax, drone_ymax = self.drone_coordinates[1][0], self.drone_coordinates[1][1]

        balloon_xmin, balloon_ymin = self.balloon_coordinates[0][0], self.balloon_coordinates[0][1]
        balloon_xmax, balloon_ymax = self.balloon_coordinates[1][0], self.balloon_coordinates[1][1]

        drone_center_x = drone_xmax - self.drone.width/2
        drone_center_y = drone_ymax - self.drone.height/2

        if balloon_xmax >= drone_center_x >= balloon_xmin and balloon_ymax >= drone_center_y >= balloon_ymin:
            for balloon in self.balloons:
                self.remove_widget(balloon)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.move_clouds()
        self.move_balloons()
        self.check_drone_collect_balloon()

        self.drone.pos[1] += self.current_speed_y
        self.drone.pos[0] += self.current_speed_x
        if self.drone.pos[1] <= 0:
            self.drone.pos[1] = 0

        elif self.drone.pos[1] >= self.height - 70:
            self.drone.pos[1] = self.height - 70

        if self.drone.pos[0] <= -10:
            self.drone.pos[0] = -10

        elif self.drone.pos[0] >= self.width - 80:
            self.drone.pos[0] = self.width - 80

class BalloonGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (.2, .6, .8, 1)
        xd = MainWidget()
        return xd


BalloonGameApp().run()
```

This is the entire code of my program, what I am trying to do is increment 1 to the variable SCORE every time a balloon is "collected".

```
def check_drone_collect_balloon(self):
        self.get_drone_coordinates()
        self.get_balloon_coordinates()

        drone_xmax, drone_ymax = self.drone_coordinates[1][0], self.drone_coordinates[1][1]

        balloon_xmin, balloon_ymin = self.balloon_coordinates[0][0], self.balloon_coordinates[0][1]
        balloon_xmax, balloon_ymax = self.balloon_coordinates[1][0], self.balloon_coordinates[1][1]

        drone_center_x = drone_xmax - self.drone.width/2
        drone_center_y = drone_ymax - self.drone.height/2

        if balloon_xmax >= drone_center_x >= balloon_xmin and balloon_ymax >= drone_center_y >= balloon_ymin:
            for balloon in self.balloons:
                self.remove_widget(balloon)
```

this function is the one that determines when a balloon is "collected" though when I try to add...

```
for balloon in self.balloons:
     self.remove_widget(balloon)
     self.SCORE += 1
     print(self.SCORE)
```

I would expect that the self.SCORE variable would increase by 1 with every balloon that gets "collected" but what happens is that the variable's value increases a lot, up to 60 or even 100 or more with every singular balloon that gets removed. I'm assuming that this happens due to it being inside a for loop, but I don't exactly understand why it happens since the "self.balloons" list would only have 1 item i.e. 1 balloon --as a result of only 1 balloon appearing every 7 seconds-- in it so the loop should only be triggered once.

Are there any suggestions as to how I could make the scoring system work? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
if balloon_xmax >= drone_center_x >= balloon_xmin and balloon_ymax >= drone_center_y >= balloon_ymin:
    for balloon in self.balloons:
        self.balloons.remove(balloon)
        self.remove_widget(balloon)
        self.SCORE += 1
        print(self.SCORE)
```

I added the function to remove balloons from the self.balloons list. But now the self.SCORE function is incremented twice so with each balloon that gets "collected" two is added to the score rather than one. How could I fix this without having to increment self.SCORE by .5

Comment: I don't see any balloons ever being removed from the `self.balloons` list, so that list just keeps growing.

Comment: That makes sense, I've added a "self.balloons.remove(balloon)" function, but now self.SCORE is incremented twice rather than once, so 2 is added with every balloon that gets "collected"